# Magento2: Error in order creation even after successful payment and redirection

Tags: order-email, magento-2.1.8

We use custom-SMTP mailer to send mails on order confirmation, invoice etc,

magentov2.1.8

The heidelpay returns a positive ACK and Transaction succeed alert. and proper redirection to success page. But because of this exception order is not getting created in the backend.

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Payment\Helper\Data::getInfoBlockHtml() must implement
>   interface Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface, null given, called in
>   /home/vapewun0/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php
>   on line 152 and defined in
>   /home/vapewun0/public_html/vendor/magento/module-payment/Helper/Data.php:204
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/vapewun0/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php(152):
>   Magento\Payment\Helper\Data->getInfoBlockHtml(NULL, '2') #1
>   /home/vapewun0/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php(125):
>   Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender->getPaymentHtml(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor))
>
> 2
>   /home/vapewun0/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php(71):
>
> Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender->prepareTemplate(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor))
>
> 3 /home/vapewun0/public_html/vendor/magento/modul in
>   /home/vapewun0/public_html/vendor/magento/module-payment/Helper/Data.php
>
> on line 204

**NOTE:** This issue happens only for transaction which involve Heidelpay. Paypal payments goes through successfully.

Comment: have you create form & info block under block section ?

Comment: @Yogesh  This is the custom module we use https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp?files=1 and no additional code is added. working for PayPal without issues , but only when heidelpay is used this issue arises